# how to normalize differnce map in c++ using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to normalize difference map in such a way that-
1. Nornalize the values in the map to fixed range [0..M]
2. Finding M(Global Maxima in the diffrence image) and m(mean of all other   local maxima)
3.globally multyplying the map by square of (M-m)

But I am not getting proper output...
Scaling factor is too high.. about 23000.. shouldn't it be between 0-255?

```
int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("lena.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   
    Mat img1,diff;   

    if (img.empty()) //if unsuccessful, exit the program
    {
            cout << "Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
            return -1;
    }

    int m,n;
    m=(int)(img.rows/2);
    n=(int)(img.cols/2);
    resize(img, img1,Size(m,n));        //downsample by 2

    resize(img1, img1,img.size(), 0, 0, CV_INTER_NN);  //interpolation by 2

    absdiff(img,img1,diff);


    //------to find global maxima present in the image-------------
    double min2,max2;
    Point x,y;
    minMaxLoc(diff,&min2,&max2,&x,&y);
    cout<<"global max= "<<max2<<" location= "<<y<<endl;

    //--to find local maximas present in the image using 5*5 kernel----
    double min1,max1;
    double val[2025];
    int count=0;
    Mat arr=Mat::zeros(5,5,img.type());
    int i,j,a,b,a1;
    for(a=0;a<diff.rows;a=a+5)
    {
        for(b=0;b<diff.cols;b=b+5)
        {
            m=n=0;
            for(i=a;i<a+5;i++)
            {
               for(j=b;j<b+5;j++)
               {                
                  a1=diff.at<uchar>(i,j);
                  arr.at<uchar>(m,n)=a1;                
                  n++;          
               }
               m++;n=0;
            }   
            minMaxLoc(arr,&min1,&max1);
            val[count]=max1;
            count++;
        }   
    }

    double sum=0,mean;  
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+val[i];
    }

    mean=sum/count;
    cout<<"count="<<count<<endl;
    cout<<"sum= "<<sum<<endl;
    cout<<"mean= "<<mean<<endl;     

    double scale;
    scale=pow((max2-mean),2);
    cout<<"scale= "<<scale;

    imshow("original",diff);
    imshow("normalized output",scale*diff); 
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code is missing `1. Nornalize the values in the map to fixed range [0..M]`. The rest should be ok. If you don't choose `M` or choose `M = 255` your squared scale factor might be anything from `0..65025` for 8 bit type. So it's all about the choise of `M` which wouldnt even be important if you had no data type limits.

Answer (score 0):

Your scale variable is squared in your code:

`scale=pow((max2-mean),2);` means `(max2-mean)^2` which is `(M-m)^2`

you asked for `scale = (M-m)` instead, which would be `scale = max2-mean;` in code if I see that right.

Comment: link the paper please. But then I dont understand, why you expect `(M-m)^2` to be in between `0..255`

Comment: probably you have to convert your image to float/double type and choose an appropriate `M` first (maybe `M=1`?)

Comment: Link for the paper which I am reffering http://www.lira.dist.unige.it/teaching/SINA_08-09/papers/itti98model.pdf      Pg. no. 2

Comment: as far as I see, your code should be correct. If you want your output to be values between 0..255 you should choose `M` to be `sqrt(255)` (if your max value in the diff-image was 255). Since you'll lose a lot of information if you divide your whole image by 1/sqrt(255), you'd better work with float or double valued images there and maybe even choose a different `M`